# Publishing Queue display wrong time

Tags: 2011

In Our environments below issue is observed.

Different time is shown in Publishing queue.

- Under Publishing queue>Publishing Tasks shows  a time(System time+4 hours)
- When we open one Publishing Task and view Transaction Details we see System time(Actual time when publishing started)

Has anyone faced such issues with Tridion.

I am using Tridion 2011 Sp1 with HR1.

Time zone information

- Publisher/CME in EST
- DB in UTC.

Comment: Can you share the screen shot?

Comment: I have updated my question with further details. @PankajGaur

Comment: Strange!! Looks like a bug as even I am getting the same behaviour, the difference is although of 1 hours

Comment: I cannot repeat this behavior on my machine... The difference in the errors is certainly interesting. What are your time zones relative to UTC?

Comment: My environments are in UTC itself and I am checking by taking remote desktop into it

Comment: To me it looks like an issue with the Day Light Saving; seems day light saving has not been handled. For all published task where day light saving is in effect, it is showing me a difference of 1 hour and for those tasks which have been published while Day Light is not in place, there is no difference at all.
@b00tbu9: By any case are you in UTC+3:00 timezone?

Comment: In my experience, daylight savings time is nearly always the culprit in time problems :P

Comment: I am using EST timeing in both the Servers. Regarding Day light saving I see almost 4 hour difference. 
Actual Publishing time: 4:16 AM
Reported time in Publishing Queue:8:16 AM

Comment: Below is the information on Server timezones
Publisher/CME in EST
DB in UTC.

Answer (score 5):

Is the time set differently on your content delivery server than on your content manager? Another possibility might be a difference between your editorial CM server and your publisher CM. I'm speculating here: generally I'd agree that DST would be a likely culprit, but not for a 4 hour difference. For that much difference I'd be looking at a difference between servers.

Comment: Both the servers in EST time.